# Reload Collection view that is inside a uitableviewcell when data from a url is downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So i have a collection views in table view cells , no in table view class data from url is downloaded , lets say images are downloaded and then i need to show those images on those collection view cell , so what i am doing is reloading table view but collection views are not reloading and i need to reload those with the downloaded data

Comment: Why don't you use background loading on image view from url? Like sd_webimage library?

Comment: yes i will do that but first i need to fetch the list of urls of images

Comment: once that list has been fetched i want to send it to cell and reload the collection view there , i have put an outlet there but it is nil when i try to reload data in it

Comment: use lazy-loading if possible https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Get Collectiview from subviews of tableview cell. Try to reload that collection view it will work.

Comment: thank you everyone for comments
I'm able to reload now but now I'm unable to switch index of tab bar from uitableviewcell class in on uicollectionview item selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it's really easy (assuming that you have your viewController, customTableViewCell and customCollectionViewCell working correctly), use this code in the controller that you are declaring your table view anytime you need to reload collectionViews inside a table view cell:

// In your ViewController

```
var myRow = 0 // set the index path row of your tableview cell
var mySection = 0 // and the index path section 

 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if let index = IndexPath(row: myRow, section: mySection) as? IndexPath {
             if let cell = self.MyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: index) as? MyCustomTableViewCell {
                cell.collectionReloadData()
             }
       }
 })
```

Now in your TableViewCell

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    func collectionReloadData(){
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
         })
    }

//Dont forget to set delegates    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }    
}
```

Here you have an example of this code in action, collection view in section 3 "Cartas Recomendadas" was reloaded:

[image]